# Python SyntaxError for open()

Tags: python

Tutorial

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

```
>>> with open('workfile', 'r') as f:
...     read_data = f.read()
>>> f.closed
True
```

My code,
In python 2.7.5

```
with open(filea, 'r') as f:
        ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is that a syntax error??

Comment: There is none, so it's something going wrong in different part of code.

Comment: can you try it again ? Looks fine to me

Comment: Can you show some code surrounding that statement?

Comment: @Puciek thats what I thought. i dont know why its raising the error? I am running with -Wd, does that affect it?

Comment: Post the whole log from running this file, and also python --version

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're not running your code in 2.7.5; you're running it in something earlier, probably 2.4 or 2.5.

```
~$ ~/sys/Python-2.5.6/python
Python 2.5.6 (r256:88840, Jul 12 2012, 12:21:58) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux3
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> with open("fred") as f:
<stdin>:1: Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    with open("fred") as f:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Add `import sys` and `print sys.version` to see the real version you're using.

Comment: If this is the case, you could use `from __future__ import with_statement`. Better to upgrade the Python version though.